Nonstandard Analysis research project ideas
Before I ask my question, this is my first post on MSE, so I apologise if I have not met the standard etiquette of a post.
I have finished my first year at a UK univeristy for a maths degree. In our second year we are asked to conduct some form of research on a topic of our choice. (I don't have much idea what this entails, but I know it's not finding anything original and proving it ourselves, it's more about wider reading.)
I've very much enjoyed my first year analysis content (sequences, series, continuity, differentiability, integrability, and power series). This has all been done on the reals.
I really want to look at more analysis content, I am interested in looking at multivariable or complex analysis but we will be taught that in our 2nd year so I wouldn't be allowed to do my project on those. Most stuff I've seen outside that seems locked behind norms, measures or metrics - these topics also have the issue of being taught in the 2nd year.
I'm sure I would be able to do a topic that dives into these a little bit and don't need much from them, but I wouldn't if the bulk of the topic requires establishing a lot of results from those topics.
I've been considering looking at non-standard analysis but I don't think my understanding of logic (doing fitch-style proofs) is sufficient.
For reference, outside of analysis we have studied a bit of groups, rings and fields, some linear algebra on finite dimensional vector spaces, basic set theory and a tiny bit of number theory, and multivariable calculus (not multivariable analysis).

Sorry, but this is off-topic here - we cannot offer advice on academic projects. Best to ask a professor that knows your background

This is a reasonable reference-request question that should be reopened.

I do also think it's a reasonable reference request.

I agree that it is a reasonable reference request.

@SeanRoberson, your comment, coming as it does 20 minutes after the first post by a new user, is not very nurturing.  You could profitably delete it.

I agree that there is no need to turn away curious students who are interested in project ideas and send them to a professor when we do not even know what university they are based in.

There are two approaches to non-standard analysis: (1) the "extension"
approach and (2) the axiomatic approach.
In the "extension" approach, the real numbers are extended to the
hyperreals, and one proves a transfer principle that enables the use
of infinitesimals in calculus, analysis, and other fields.
In the axiomatic approach, one enriches the $\in$-language of
traditional set theory (where $\in$ is the membership relation).  This
is done by adding a new one-place predicate "standard".  One also adds
additional axioms that govern the interaction of the predicate with
the traditional set-theoretic axioms.  In this approach, $\mathbb R$
is not extended; rather, infinitesimals (and unlimited numbers) are
found within $\mathbb R$ itself.
If you would like to explore approach (1) for your presentation, a
good starting point would be the book by Goldblatt from 1998.  You
could for example present the infinitesimal proofs of traditional
results such as the extreme value theorem.  Also appealing are the
definition of continuity, integral, etc., in terms of infinitesimals.
This would make the point that going back to using infinitesimals a la
Leibniz actually provides a significant simplification of the
calculus.
If you would like to explore approach (2), you could use this
introduction as a
starting point.  It is nice to know that one can do infinitesimals
without the axiom of choice, thereby refuting various ad
ultrafiltrinem (a pun on ad hominem) criticisms.
